# Printing a name only if it is longer than the one before it

Tags: python

Suppose you have a namelist ["sam", "janet", "bob","samantha"].
How would you write a program in Python such that it prints the name only if it is longer than the one before it.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: for f in ["vusi", "angelina", "uma", "johnny", "sizwe", "kate", "charlize", "meryl"]:
    x=len(f)
    if x>
        print(f)
but i dont know what to put for x>......

Comment: Use indexes and [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function. Something like: for i in range(len(mylist)): do_something with mylist[i] and mylist[i-1]. I think you will figure the correct range and supposed operations yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `pairwise` recipe from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) with a list comprehension strikes me as the most pythonic way:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, tee
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return izip(a, b)
...
>>> namelist = ["sam", "janet", "bob","samantha"]
>>> [b for a,b in pairwise(namelist) if len(b) > len(a)]
['janet', 'samantha']
```

### Update

It's not clear from your question whether the first name in the `list` should be counted as longer or shorter than the *none* before it. The above solution excludes it. If you (or your teacher?) want the first item included:

```
>>> [namelist[0]] + [b for a,b in pairwise(namelist) if len(b) > len(a)]
['sam', 'janet', 'samantha']
```

Comment: It looks like I **should** read through itertools documentation. I like your solution, even it is not the best for beginner.

Comment: @Fenikso: `itertools`' documentation makes for fascinating reading. There's a wealth of good stuff in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["sam", "janet", "bob", "samantha"]

# two similar one-liners:
print ', '.join(a2 for a1, a2 in zip(a[:-1],a[1:]) if len(a2) > len(a1))
print ', '.join(a[i] for i in xrange(1, len(a)) if len(a[i]) > len(a[i-1]))

# output of both of them:
janet, samantha
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `sam` printed too for both lists?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: There was nothing before "Sam", so we don't know whether it is shorter or longer. I guess the OP (or their teacher) needs to refine the specification.

Comment: @Ocaso Protal - it won't be printed by my code. OP has to decide whether it should.

Answer (score 2):

Only 5 answers so far. *None of them prints the first name*. Of course many could easily be altered to do so, but just for the heck of it, here's one that does. I'll break it down nicely.

The python [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module is the greatest thing since eleven foot poles, and one particularly promising iterator for this problem is `ifilter`, which calls a given function on each item in a list, and outputs only those for which the function returns `True`. So we would like to do something like this:

```
from itertools import ifilter

names = ["sam", "janet", "bob", "jane", "samantha"]
for name in ifilter(longer_than_previous, names):
    print name   # Output: sam (?), janet, jane, samantha
```

So our as yet undefined function `longer_than_previous` will be called first with "sam" as the argument, then "janet", "bob", and so on. Now the problem is that functions in general have no memory, so we need some kind of trick to make the function remember the length of the last argument and compare it to the length of the current one.

The naïve way of doing that is with a global argument. Assume the following code was pasted before the code given above:

```
last_name_length = 0

def longer_than_previous(name):
    global last_name_length
    is_longer = len(name) > last_name_length
    last_name_length = len(name)
    return is_longer
```

Now, using globals to store values that are actually needed only one place is considered bad practice. Is there another way to give our function memory? Well, in python, everything is an object, so we can just give the function itself an attribute (*warning*, ugly code ahead):

```
def longer_than_previous(name):
    if not hasattr(longer_than_previous, "last_name_length"):
        longer_than_previous.last_name_length = 0
    is_longer = len(name) > longer_than_previous.last_name_length
    longer_than_previous.last_name_length = len(name)
    return is_longer
```

Well that didn't exactly improve readability, and we have to use `hasattr`, which I find is a good indication I've designed something badly. Also, this function is only useable once, after that we have to manually reset it with `longer_than_previous.last_name_length = 0`. So we want to be able to make several throwaway functions like this, each with an attribute to store the last length in. Well, that sounds like a good job for a class. A class is, after all, something that produces objects with attributes when called. But the objects need to act like a function. This we can achieve with the `__call__` special method, like this:

```
class LongerThanPrevious(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name_length = 0

    def __call__(self, name):
        is_longer = len(name) > self.last_name_length
        self.last_name_length = len(name)
        return is_longer
```

Now we only need to alter the code at the top, so that it uses an object of the `LongerThanPrevious` class instead of the function longer_than_previous:

```
for name in ifilter(LongerThanPrevious(), names):
    print name   # Output: sam (?), janet, jane, samantha
```

Now that's much better, and quite readable. I've put a question mark after sam, because the question leaves open whether it should be included or not. It's easy to alter the class so it is not included:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name_length = float("infinity")
```

**Note:** Answer has been completely rewritten.

Comment: What? My answer prints the first name. Funny answer though.

Comment: So it does. If you add proper whitespace (ref [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) around the operators I'll give you a +1. :)

Comment: Pffft, whitespace! I save the bytes! ;)

Comment: @Ocaso Meh, I'll give you a +1 anyway, 'cause I feel like it. And it ruins your nice round score of 2000. HAH!

Comment: +1. Mine deliberately doesn't print the first name. 
There was nothing before "Sam", so we don't know whether it is shorter or longer. I guess the OP (or their teacher) needs to refine the specification.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Of course it's not clear what the OP wants, but for me it's natural that the first name should be printed. I'll update my answer with a variant that doesn't though, to show how to do that too, using this approach.

Comment: Damn, @lazyr I hate you! I wanted that 2k score forever! Now I have to continue to 10k. :D

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward:

```
oldlen=0
for f in ["vusi", "angelina", "uma", "johnny", "sizwe", "kate", "charlize", "meryl"]:
    x=len(f) 
    if x>oldlen:
        print(f)
    oldlen=x
```

The idea is to store the previous printed length in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
names = ["sam", "janet", "bob","samantha"]
last_name = None
for name in names:
    if last_name and len(name) > len(last_name):
        print name
    last_name = name
```

or (in a more pythonic way):

```
names = ["sam", "janet", "bob","samantha"]
print '\n'.join(name for i, name in enumerate(names) if i>0 and len(name) > len(names[i-1]))
```

of course, the first name won't ever be printed.